# .NET Core 3.x how to map the default razor page to pages\Index.cshtm. I don't have controller but use Razor pages (CRUD)

Tags: asp.net-core

I am creating the application for .NET Core 3.x using Razor pages (CRUD). How do i map to a default Razor Page for example Customer/Index page. I don't use controller model to Razor page.
endpoints.MapRazorPages();  - This always goes to the default Index page on the Pages folder.
I would like to set the default page to go to "Customer/Index"
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @anithac, I already posted the code to solve your question. It works on me. If the answer solved your question, please mark it for helping more people. If not, we may be able to continue to explore solutions. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Include MVC as a service into our app.**
we can optionally use another method called `AddRazorPagesOptions()` like so:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Customer/Index", "");
        });
```

Within that `AddRazorPagesOptions()` method, we can set things like route conventions and the root directory for pages. It turns out that, to set a default route for a page.

**2. remove or rename Pages/Index.cshtml**
[image]

> Test

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have to change the name Index.cshtml that worked.